# How to confirm my first meeting with Japanese teacher

Tags: synonyms

I am a beginner and my first meeting with my new Japanese tutor is today. I want to send her a message to confirm that 6pm today is still ok for her but I am certain my phrasing is not correct. Could someone please advise?

I had 今日６じはまだだいじょうぶですか？

But I don't think mada is right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 今日６じはまだだいじょうぶですか？

This makes sense.
If you are still anxious about the confirmation, how about writing it in both languages as:

> 今日６じはまだだいじょうぶですか？
>   Is 6pm today still ok?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I am not confident in my grammar as it's been a few years but I'm pleased that it worked ok.